# handle if else in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I want use if-else to handle show an item when the value is not null.
when  vars.request-id != null or not isEmpty(vars.request-id)
output {requestID:"" ,origin_uri:"", errorDesc: ""}

when vars.request-id == null or isEmpty(vars.request-id)
output {origin_uri:"", errorDesc: ""}

but the following code is Unable to resolve

```
{
   requestID : ("Midend-correlation-id": vars.request-id) if (vars.request-id != null) 
   origin_uri: vars.errorContent.uri
   errorDesc: vars.errorContent.message
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and expected output ? That helps better than explaining at times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after? I am not very clear on the ask and from what i understand i tried to scribble something for you. Maybe a clear input , some condition and the expected output would help..

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, it showed "Unable to resolve" in my project.  but it can pass in my testing